# Can anyone help me out with the ASCII part please

Tags: python, encryption, ascii

My task is to encrypt and decrypt coding and also create a button or a word that will exit the program. Now, I have worked out how to do that but now I have to use ASCII and I need a bit of help... This is my code for just encrypting, decrypting and exit below. Can anyone help me out with the ASCII part please...

```
    welcome = input("Hello there...")
    letters = ("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z")

    numberShift = int(input("How much do you wish to shift the letters? "))
    phrase = input("Enter a phrase to be encrypted: ")
    newPhrase = ""
    for l in phrase:
    if l in letters:
    pos = letters.index(l) + numberShift
    if pos > 25:
        pos = pos - 26
    newPhrase += letters[pos]
else:
    newPhrase += " "
    print(newPhrase)

    numberShift = int(input("How many times has the code you want to decrypt been shifted? "))
    phrase = input("Enter a phrase to be decrypted: ")
    newPhrase = ""
    for l in phrase:
if l in letters:
    pos = letters.index(l) - numberShift
    if pos > 25:
        pos = pos - 26
    newPhrase += letters[pos]
else:
    newPhrase += " "
    print(newPhrase)

exit1 = input("Do you want to exit?")

if 'yes' in exit1:
   exit()
```

Comment: your indentation is off, you may want to fix. What exactly is your problem?

Comment: @depperm: I don't think the indentation is off.  It looks like he just left out the line with the `if` part.

Comment: Are you familiar with `ord` and `chr`? If not -- read up on them. They are fairly easy to use and are the key to your problem.

Comment: First of all I'm a girl ( not that it matters), secondly, what if part and finally, I want to know how to add ASCII into it therefore it being harder to hack.

Comment: Indentation is completely messed up. There's `for` and right after that `if` with the same indentation. Fix the indentation first, it's hard to tell what should it do :)

Comment: yes i do know about ord and chr my teacher told me about them but i don't understsand how to add them in. I havent used them before and i know of them just not much about them

Comment: As a hint -- what you are computing as `letters.index(l)` can be computed much more efficiently as `ord(l) - ord('a')`

Comment: Your code seems to be missing an `if` statement before the  `numberShift = int(` line that decides whether you're encrypting or decrypting.

Comment: i don't understand what everyone keeps saying referring to indentation this is how m teacher said to do it when i first started to use python for a different assignment and all I've done is use it in this assignment as well

Comment: @camconnolly Your code isn't valid Python. Bad indentation is just a stylistic problem -- it is a syntax error.

Comment: @JohnColeman: Sure, using `ord` and `chr` would be good, but they aren't totally _necessary_: the core of cam's encrypting & decrypting code is ok. But there are a few minor glitches that need to be repaired, like the `newPhrase += " "` under the `else:` statement.

Comment: @PM2Ring OP states that she has been instructed to use ASCII -- hence they are necessary for that.

Comment: ok john coleman so how do I use

Comment: chr to change it to ASCII

Comment: As in where do i put it

Comment: @JohnColeman: Ah, ok. Yes, if she wants to encrypt / decrypt the full ASCII range of characters and not just lower-case letters then using `chr`/`ord` will make things neater.

Comment: no its just lower case ,

Comment: somewhere in la mancha, in a place whose name I do not care to remember, a gentleman lived not long ago, one of those who has a lance and ancient shield on a shelf and keeps a skinny nag and a greyhound for racing.

Comment: `ord('a') = 97`, so the expression `ord(c) - 97` gets you from a character in the range 'a' to 'z' to a number in the range 0 to 25, and the expression `chr(i+97)` gets you back from a number `i` in the range 0 to 25 to a letter in the range 'a' to 'z'

Comment: How does you program decide whether to encrypt or decrypt? And what do you want to do about the spaces and punctuation in your sample input?

Comment: it doesnt need to decide yet I'm not at that stage. I've just got to get it to encrypt and decrypt in whatever order first and then add that later. Also the booklet I've been given says to include all punctuation but the program has to know no to convert spaces.

Comment: could i use this to generate an 8 character key?

Comment: def generateKey():
    key = []
    for count in range(0,8):
        randomInteger = random.randint(33,126)
        
        character = chr(randomInteger)
        key.append(character)
    print("encryption key: ", ''.join(key))
    return key @John Coleman

Comment: Please save that `generateKey` stuff for a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a repaired version of your code. Correct indentation is *very* important in Python because that's how you group code into blocks. If the code indentation is wrong neither the Python interpreter nor humans reading your program can tell what you want it to do.

We can simplify `letters` into a single string, rather than a tuple of strings.

The main change I made copies characters that aren't in `letters` to `newPhrase` without shifting them. This means that spaces and punctuation just get copied, but it also means that numbers and upper-case letters will also just get copied.

I also put your program into a big loop so that the `"Do you want to exit? "` stuff is meaningful. Otherwise, the program will just exit anyway.

```
letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" 

welcome = print("Hello there!")

while True:
    #Encrypt
    numberShift = int(input("How much do you wish to shift the letters? "))
    phrase = input("Enter a phrase to be encrypted: ")
    newPhrase = ""
    for l in phrase:
        #Only change characters that aren't in letters
        if l in letters:
            pos = letters.index(l) + numberShift
            if pos > 25:
                pos = pos - 26
            l = letters[pos]
        newPhrase += l

    print(newPhrase)

    #Decrypt
    numberShift = int(input("How many times has the code you want to decrypt been shifted? "))
    phrase = input("Enter a phrase to be decrypted: ")
    newPhrase = ""
    for l in phrase:
        #Only change characters that aren't in letters
        if l in letters:
            pos = letters.index(l) - numberShift
            if pos > 25:
                pos = pos - 26
            l = letters[pos]
        newPhrase += l

    print(newPhrase)

    if 'yes' in input("Do you want to exit? "):
        break
```

**test output**

```
Hello there!
How much do you wish to shift the letters? 3
Enter a phrase to be encrypted: somewhere in la mancha, in a place whose name I do not care to remember, a gentleman lived not long ago, one of those who has a lance and ancient shield on a shelf and keeps a skinny nag and a greyhound for racing.
vrphzkhuh lq od pdqfkd, lq d sodfh zkrvh qdph I gr qrw fduh wr uhphpehu, d jhqwohpdq olyhg qrw orqj djr, rqh ri wkrvh zkr kdv d odqfh dqg dqflhqw vklhog rq d vkhoi dqg nhhsv d vnlqqb qdj dqg d juhbkrxqg iru udflqj.
How many times has the code you want to decrypt been shifted? 3
Enter a phrase to be decrypted: vrphzkhuh lq od pdqfkd, lq d sodfh zkrvh qdph I gr qrw fduh wr uhphpehu, d jhqwohpdq olyhg qrw orqj djr, rqh ri wkrvh zkr kdv d odqfh dqg dqflhqw vklhog rq d vkhoi dqg nhhsv d vnlqqb qdj dqg d juhbkrxqg iru udflqj.
somewhere in la mancha, in a place whose name I do not care to remember, a gentleman lived not long ago, one of those who has a lance and ancient shield on a shelf and keeps a skinny nag and a greyhound for racing.
Do you want to exit? yes
```